# DbContext Dispose is extremely slow after any Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dispose, dbcontext, savechanges

I've updated my code to properly dispose of all my EF6 `DbContext` objects after use, via a `using` statement (according to almost everyone in the online community). So now I can see exactly how long it takes to call `dispose`.

What I've discovered is that the `DBContext` goes away in milliseconds, *unless* the `DbContext` has had piece of content modified, and a `SaveChanges` command executed against it. When that happens (on any piece of content), then the disposal takes about 13 seconds.

Obviously, I can't see what the Dispose command is actually doing behind the scenes, but it's ridiculously slow and I am not sure how to proceed. Suggestions?

Comment: I believe it is your save changes call that is taking 13 seconds.

Comment: How did you measure this observed delay?

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio 2015, and I can step over the SaveChanges line (it's almost immediate). Then I put a breakpoint at the closing brace of the Using statement and step one line. It calls the dispose method and comes back 13 sec. later.

Comment: That doesn't seem accurate. I am unable to reproduce your example.

Comment: Are you saying you're unable to use the debugger to measure how long it takes to call the Dispose method, or that you can't reproduce the 13-second delay I'm seeing? I understand that it's not expected behaviour; that's why I'm asking StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure if has any effect, but FYI I'm using my own derived DbContext, which inherits from IdentityDbContext. I've just overloaded the Dispose method and confirmed that it's the IdentityDbContext.Dispose base method that takes 13 seconds to run (but only if I've previously called SaveChanges).

Comment: Dispose just closes the connection to the database. It doesn't cause side effects. The using statement you are using coupled with the implicit Dispose is essentially doing a `try{ db.SaveChanges(); }finally{ db.Close(); }` from a very basic point of view. The close should be almost instantaneous. The SaveChanges is going to cause a very large amount of work to occur. Are you using async? If not, no, I could not reproduce a 13 second delay only on Dispose. And I do know how to use a debugger, although I would use a StopWatch for timing observations.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some of your custom code if you are overriding Dispose.

Comment: The SaveChanges is instantanious. "protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { base.Dispose(disposing); }" takes 13 seconds.

Comment: This isn't answerable without a complete, working example.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's just the debugger that's acting strange. Sometimes the debugger consistently takes a long time to step over simple function calls. Try measuring the time in release mode without a debugger attached.

Comment: I've discovered that the problem is actually due to my additional DBConfiguration's transactionHandler "CommitFailureHandler". When I turn off the failure handler, everything goes back to full speed! This probably means I should re-submit this question in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is actually due to my additional DBConfiguration's transactionHandler "CommitFailureHandler". When I turn off the failure handler, everything goes back to full speed! It turns out that the `__TransactionHistory` table had grown to a very large size.

I created a SQL script to manually delete old records, as-needed...

```
delete from [__TransactionHistory] where CreationTime <  DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
```

I'm sure there's an automatic way to do this, but for our application, it can simply be done by hand, once in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with a Azure SQL Database. We configurate your EntityFramework based on the [msdn Documentation over Handling of Transaction Commit Failures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630221(v=vs.113).aspx)

After we detect this problem we remove this line of code, to turn this feature off again:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration  
{ 
  public MyConfiguration()  
  {  
    // SetTransactionHandler(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new CommitFailureHandler());  
    SetExecutionStrategy(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());  
  }  
}
```

Based of the [codeplex Documentation Handling of Transaction Commit Failures](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20of%20Transaction%20Commit%20Failures%20) you can add this code at application start to clean up the __TransactionHistory table.

```
var commitFailureHandler = CommitFailureHandler.FromContext(context);
if (commitFailureHandler != null)
{
    commitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory();
}
```